# Can the user restore purchased non-consumable product after this product id (in-App purchase) was deleted from iTunesConnect?

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase

Here is a situation. A user purchases some non-consumable product (which once purchased should be available for the user everywhere and automatically restored) through in-App Purchase mechanism. After some time developer decides to update list of in-App purchases assigned to this app in iTunes Connect and deletes (or removes from sale) corresponding in-App purchase product id.

The question is what would happen if the user for some reason deleted previously purchased content and then decided to restore it (or installed the app on a new device and activated  restoration mechanism for completed transactions)?

Is it possible to stop selling particular product (and remove corresponding in-App purchase) while keeping restoration working for the users who already bought it?

Thanks in advance.